# Algorithm to find shortest time span for fixed ascent.

Tags: algorithms

I have discrete dataset of values for $f(t)$. I now want to find the shortest amount of time $(dt)$ where the data "ascends" a certain amount $(x)$. So I want to find the minimal $dt$, where $f(t+dt) - f(t) = x$.

I need a efficient algorithm for this problem, which I can then implement as python or fortran code.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: what hypothesis do you have on f? Do you know that f is growing?

Comment: No, f(t) is not monotonously increasing, if that is what you mean.

Comment: Yes it's what I mean by "growing" (which is the litteral translation of a french expression... so not sure it's the correct expression here)

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstand your answer and didn't see the "not"... Without any hypothesis, the only thing you can do is sequentially test: $f(t+1)-f(t)$ then $f(t+2) -f(t)$, then $f(t+3)-f(t)$... So what are your hypothesis?

Comment: I have a data set with 100k+ data arrays. All I know is that the data is "continuous" (discrete obviously, as it is data from a model at certain time steps).

Comment: What do you mean by "continuous" if your data are discrete ? It's opposite notions.

Comment: well, forget about the discrete. It is a continuous function.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is  monotonously increasing (i.e. for all $t_1$ and $t_2$ s.t. $t_1<t_2$ then $f(t_1)<f(t_2)$), you can perform a can of dichotomy in two steps:

1. "Ascending step": first test if $f(t+1)-f(t)> x$. If not, double your $dt$ and test if  $f(t+2)-f(t)> x$. If not double your $dt$ and test if  $f(t+4)-f(t)> x$ etc. When you reach a $dt$ such that $f(t+dt)-f(t)>x$, you kown that your searched value is between $dt/2$ and $dt$. Then you can pass to step 2:
2. Perform a classical dichotomy.

This algorithm find your $dt$ in about $2\log_2(n)$ comparisons where $n$ is the searched $dt$.

Comment: No, f(t) is not monotonously increasing. It can have several local maxima and minima

Comment: Yes it's what I mean by "growing" ...

Answer (score 0):

Here are two approaches that will give you $O(n \log n)$ time algorithm.

First, start by precomputing sum of prefixes, so that you can calculate sum of intervals in $O(1)$ time, that is

$$A[k] = \sum_{i \leq k}f(i), \quad \mathrm{Sum}(i,j) = A[j+1]-A[i].$$

Now, one approach is to use [range minimum query](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_Minimum_Query) (you can nice tutorial [here](http://www.topcoder.com/tc?d1=tutorials&d2=lowestCommonAncestor&module=Static)), so that for each element $A[i]$ you can binary search the smallest $j$ such that maximum $\max_{i \leq k \leq j}A[k]$ is greater or equal $A[i]+x$.

The second approach is to use [sweeping line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm). In this case the sweeping line might go from right to left, and it would hold a set $B$ of elements such that at index $i$ (i.e. the sweeping line is there)

> $b \in B$     if and only if     $b$ is visible looking right from $i$, in other words,
>   $b$ is the largest element in the interval from $A[i]$ to the place where $b$ is in $A$.

This could be stated easier in operational terms,

> Let $B$ be an array-based stack (probably the easiest structure to use here). When at a new index $i$, pop elements from $B$ until the top is strictly greater than $A[i]$ and then push $A[i]$.

Then, when at point $i$, you can binary search the smallest element of $B$ such that $b \geq A[i]+x$. That would give you the smallest interval that starts at $i$ and has appropriate sum (don't forget that you need to keep the indexes of elements of $B$ too).

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$